# I'm using tcp for very many small sends, should I turn off Nagles algorithm? (People also know this as TCP_NODELAY)

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, send

I remade this post because my title choice was horrible, sorry about that. My new post can be found here: [After sending a lot, my send() call causes my program to stall completely. How is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568389/after-sending-a-lot-my-send-call-causes-my-program-to-stall-completely-how-is)

Thank you very much everyone. The problem was that the clients are actually bots and they never read from the connections. (Feels foolish)

Comment: You can simply edit your title, you know.

Comment: Haha I tried to but I couldnt figure it out.. I would've much preferred that :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TCP_NODELAY` might help latency of small packets from sender to receiver, but the description you gave points into different direction. I can imagine the following:

- Sending more data than receivers actually consume - this eventually overflows sender's buffer ([`SO_SNDBUF`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html)) and causes the server process to appear "stuck" in the [`send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) system call. At this point the kernel waits for the other end to acknowledge some of the outstanding data, but the receiver does not expect it, so it does not [`recv(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html).

There are probably other explanations, but it's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi Nikolai, I know for a fact that the clients are never reading the data. The clients are being simulated by another program. If they never receive data will that cause my own buffer to overflow?

Comment: On the second thought, it looks like UDP might fit your needs better.

Answer (score 4):

If `send()` is blocking on a TCP socket, it indicates that the send buffer is full, which in turn indicates that the peer on the other end of the connection isn't reading data fast enough.  Maybe that client is completely stuck and not calling `recv()` often enough.

Answer (score 2):

Nagle's wouldn't cause "disappearing into the kernel", which is why disabling it doesn't help you. Nagle's will just buffer data for a little while, but will eventually send it without any prompting from the user.

There is some other culprit.

---

Edit for the updated question.

You must make sure that the client is receiving all of the sent data, and that it is receiving it *quickly*. Have each client write to a log or something to verify.

For example, if a client is waiting for the server to accept its 23-byte update, then it might not be receiving the data. That can cause the server's send buffer to fill-up, which would cause degradation and eventual deadlock.

If this is indeed the culprit, the solution would be some asynchronous communication, like Boost's Asio library.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought. I'm really clue-less though. Something I've been looking at is the tcp buffer size maybe... I really don't know -_-

Comment: @returneax Can you modify your question to include the code you're using to send/recv data on both the client and server? I wonder if you are doing something to cause a deadlock, etc.

Comment: Sure, the client is written in C# and my friend is writing it but for now I can give you the server code. Also the server is multithreaded...

Comment: The multithreading is rather simple though. It's two threads which communicate through a message queue. The first thread is just listening on port 3500 for new connections. It then verifies their username and password creates a Client object and fills out its data, then passes a pointer to that object over the message queue as an array of bytes. So while no one is connecting the login thread is blocking on accept().

Comment: @return I updated my answer, but now I see Nikolai beat me to it.