# After sending a lot, my send() call causes my program to stall completely. How is this possible?

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, send

So basically I'm making an MMO server in C++ that runs on linux. It works fine at first, but after maybe 40 seconds with 50 clients it will completely pause. When I debug it I find that basically the last frame its on before it stops responding is syscall() at which point it disappears into the kernel. Once it disappears into the kernel it never even returns a value... it's completely baffling.

The 50 clients are each sending 23 bytes every 250 milliseconds. These 23 bytes are then broadcasted to all the other 49 clients. This process begins to slow down and then eventually comes to a complete halt where the kernel never returns from a syscall for the send() command. What are some possible reasons here? This is truly driving me nuts!

One option I found is Nagles algorithm which forces delays. I've tried toggling it but it still happens however.

Edit: The program is stuck here. Specifically, in the send, which in turn calls syscall()

```
bool EpollManager::s_send(int curFD, unsigned char buf[], int bufLen, int flag) 
//     Meant to counteract partial sends
{
    int sendRetVal = 0;
    int bytesSent = 0;
    while(bytesSent != bufLen)
    {
 print_buffer(buf, bufLen);
        sendRetVal = send(curFD, buf + bytesSent, bufLen - bytesSent, flag); 

        cout << sendRetVal << " ";
        if(sendRetVal == -1)
        {
            perror("Sending failed");
            return false;
        }
        else
            bytesSent += sendRetVal;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also this is the method which calls the s_send.

```
    void EpollManager::broadcast(unsigned char msg[], int bytesRead, int sender)
    {
 for(iMap = connections.begin(); iMap != connections.end(); iMap++)
 {
  if(sender != iMap->first)
  {
   if(s_send(iMap->first, msg, bytesRead, 0)) // MSG_NOSIGNAL
   {
       if(debug)
       {
                    print_buffer(msg, bytesRead);
                    cout << "sent on file descriptor " << iMap->first << '\n';
       }
   }
  }
 }
 if(connections.find(sender) != connections.end())
        connections[sender]->reset_batch();
    }
```

And to clarify connections is an instance of boost's unordered_map. The data that the program chokes on is not unique in any way either. It has been broadcast successfully to other file descriptors, but chokes on a, at least seemingly, random one.

Comment: If you're doing a blocking send, you have to make sure that something is reading at the other end to unblock the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel keeps a finite buffer for sending data.  If the receiver isn't receiving, that buffer will fill up and the sender will block.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

TCP congestion control, i.e. Nagle's algorithm, along side a full buffer (`SO_SNDBUF` socket option) will cause the `send()` and similar operations to block.

The lazy way around this is to implement separate threads for each socket but this does not scale too far.  On Linux you should use non-blocking sockets with `poll()` or similar, with Windows you would investigate IO completion ports.  Look at middleware libraries to simplify this, [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) is a popular cross platform example with recent inclusion of Windows IOCP support, alternatively [Boost:ASIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244453/best-documentation-for-boostasio) for C++.

A useful article to read on IO scalability would be [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

Note you really do not want to disable Nagle's on Internet traffic, even on a LAN you might see major problems without some form of congestion feedback.

Comment: Im currently using epoll with blocking sockets. The buffer filled up it seems.